# why doesn't my navbar bar extent to 100% despite width 100%

Tags: css

I have created a navbar that i wish to make it 100%.

Here is my HTML code for better clarity

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

<title>iPolice</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" >
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />


<ul id="nav" >
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Department</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Login.aspx">Login</a></li> 
</ul>
</head>
```

However, despite putting width:100%; It still remain the same.

[image]

I was hoping that all my 5 choices will be centered and divided evenly like this. However, i'm not even able to do it without my width being 100%.

[image]

This is the CSS of my navbar

```
#nav {
 position:absolute;
 left:0%;
 top:0%;
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px yellow;
 border-bottom: none;
 width:100%;
}

#nav li a, #nav li {
 text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

#nav li {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
 padding: 1em 2em;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #5FFB17;
 background: #292929;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, #3c3c3c 1px, #292929 25px);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(black), color-stop(4%, #3c3c3c), to(#292929));
 border-right: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
 border-left: 1px solid #292929;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #232323;
 border-top: 1px solid #545454;
}

#nav li a:hover {
 background: #2a0d65;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11032e, #2a0d65);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#11032e), to(#2a0d65));
}
```

I also have tried to change the #navbar's position to relative. However, the navbar's left, top position wont be 0% as what my code written. I cant really see anything that is holding my navbar from becoming 100%.

[image]

I have also tried nesting my navbar in a different CSS attributes with width as 100% as well

```
<div id="navbarwidth">
<ul id="nav" >
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Department</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Login.aspx">Login</a></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navbarwidth {
width:100%;
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: you ... really want to put the html markup for the nav menu in the `<body>`, not the `<head>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as icktoofay said, your `#nav` element is occupying the whole width, but the elements within it are floated left, and the nav has no background, so it looks like it isn't. Here's a fixup:

http://jsfiddle.net/DgceP/

remove the float on the `li` and `a` elements and set them to `display: inline-block`

move the background gradient to `#nav`

set `text-align: center` on `#navbarwidth`

set a min-width on the `li` elements so they will have similar widths ( except very long ones )

If you don't want the menu to wrap on small screens, set a min-width on `#navbarwidth` or `#nav`

```
#navbarwidth {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav {
    background: #292929;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, #3c3c3c 1px, #292929 25px);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(black), color-stop(4%, #3c3c3c), to(#292929));
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    top:0%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px yellow;
    border-bottom: none;
    width:100%;
}
#nav li a, #nav li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 70px;
}
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
}
#nav li a {
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5FFB17;
    border-right: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
    border-left: 1px solid #292929;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #232323;
    border-top: 1px solid #545454;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    background: #2a0d65;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11032e, #2a0d65);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#11032e), to(#2a0d65));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely because your navbar is within a div that has a finite width. Therefore, setting the navbar width to 100% only lets it fill the div it is in (not the entire page).

If this is indeed the case, simply take the navbar out of the parent div or adjust the parent div in some way. (i.e. center it, or make its width bigger)

Comment: I have added my HTML markup language above. If i have not mistaken i didnt place my navbar in any div/parent. I only added a <ul> to link it with my CSS code as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Your navigation bar *is* taking up all the horizontal space – it's just that

1. it has no height; and
2. you haven't applied a background to see it.

These problems have rather obvious solutions:

1. Apply an explicit height to the navigation bar and its elements.
2. Apply a background.

The items still won't be centered because you're doing `float: left`, but that's a different problem.

Comment: I have added a background and tested it before. The background colour actually stretched all the way to 100% but leaving the navbar behind like this. http://imgur.com/mtCp9KU. And i also tried with float as center but all the navigation will be crumbled.http://imgur.com/nnZ8Uji.
Sorry if i have mistaken your answer by any means. Regards.

Comment: @Teo: Right. `float: center;` doesn't exist. If you want to center it, you can't use `float` at all; you'll have to try a different approach. (I'd try `text-align: center;` on the container and `display: inline-block;` on each item.)

Comment: okay understood. but sorry, as for now, i'm still thinking why doesn't the navbar doesn't hit 100% with the background.

Comment: @Teo: I'm afraid I don't understand. In [your picture](http://i.imgur.com/mtCp9KU.png), it sure looks to me like the navigation bar is going all the way (100%) across the screen. If that's not what you were talking about, can you please clarify?